# Type of method parameter of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I want to set the type of the parameter like this:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_of_nodes=[]
    def inser_node (self, node: Tree):
        self.list_of_nodes.append(node)
```

When I try to do this, the error is raised: NameError: name 'Tree' is not defined

Comment: Naturally, class is not yet in namespace when it's method is being defined. You'll have to use a workaround like using string `"Tree"` instead of class reference.

Answer (score 3):

In the same class, you must place the type in quotes:

```
def inser_node (self, node: 'Tree'):
```